# Rails How to assign multiple values to an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes

I`m begginer in rails, so I am not even sure if this is possible, if not please write it to me.

My goal is to write a search function to search through db.

The form is based on the check_box_fields which sends two arrays `clan` and `class`. And then it search thorough a db. But I don`t know how to set more then one attribute value to record.

Search engine:

```
 def self.school_search(clan, class)
   School.where(clan: clan, class: class)
 end
```

and in my seed file I created few objects:

```
schools = [
  { nazwa: "Smok Bushi",
    clan: "Smok",
    class: "Bushi"
  },
  { nazwa: "Pajak Bushi",
    clan: "Pajak",
    class: "Bushi", "Shugenja"
  }
]

schools.each do |school|
  School.create(school)
end
```

Everything is well when I search for object one I send params clan: "Smok" and class "Bushi" and object is selected. But I want the second object to be found by either clan: "Pajak" class: "Bushi" or clan: "Pajak" class: "Shugenja". I tried to pass this value as an array but it didn`t help.

Edit: used english names for attributes

Answer (score 2):

You can, actually, pass an array to the attribute, as you said. So maybe you're doing something else wrong.

[Active Records' Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) is clear about that (read the "conditions" sub-section).

Edit: Adding example code for clarification

```
# This works
Model.where(title: ['Hello', 'Rails'])
```

Comment: Ok but what if model gets to the nested array? Model.where( title: [ ['foo','bar'], 'Rails' ] ? In my sample app it doesn`t seem to search through 'foo' and 'bar'. But your answer show me some light where to search :)

Comment: Well I don't see the point of passing a nested array. I mean, you want to be returned instances where Model's title is foo or bar or Rails. So when you nest the array, there is no semantic difference...

Answer (score 0):

You can not  assign multiple value for one attribute. Maybe you should create association school has many klasa and klasa belongs to school. 
P.s. it is desirable to use english words instead of polish(klasa = class)